# A system of ODE's with one less initial condition

Tags: differential-equations

I have a system of two ODE's, each of order 2 with three initial conditions. One of the condition is of the form `f(0)+g(0)=1`, which is the main reason that `NDSolve` is unable to find the solution.

Here the system with the initial conditions,

```
ode1 = f''[x] + (f[x] + g[x])*f'[x] == 0
ode2 = g''[x] + (f[x] + g[x])*g'[x] == 0
ics = {f[0] + g[0] == 1, f'[0] == 0, g'[0] == 1};
system = {ode1, ode2}
NDSolve[Join[system, ics], {f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 5}]
```

> NDSolve::ndnco: The number of constraints (3) (initial conditions) is
>   not equal to the total differential order of the system plus the
>   number of discrete variables (4)

How we can handle such situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then there should be infinite solutions. Let's introduce a parameter:

```
ode1 = f''[x] + (f[x] + g[x])*f'[x] == 0;
ode2 = g''[x] + (f[x] + g[x])*g'[x] == 0;
ics = {f[0] + g[0] == 1, f'[0] == 0, g'[0] == 1};
system = {ode1, ode2};
{solf, solg} = 
  ParametricNDSolve[{system, ics, f[0] == a}, {f, g}, {x, 0, 5}, a][[All, -1]];

Manipulate[Plot[{solf[a][x], solg[a][x]}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> 7], {a, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: How I will know that what value of `a` is the correct one?

Comment: @mmm Well, as said above, with only 3 boundary conditions, this equation set owns infinite possible solutions, so every value of `a` points to a valid solution, there's no incorrect `a`.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, then we can take `f(0)=a` and `g(0)=1-a` where $a\in R$?

Comment: @mmm Actually `a` can even be a complex number.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps define an interim function `h[x]`?

```
ode1 = f''[x] + h[x]*f'[x] == 0
ode2 = g''[x] + h[x]*g'[x] == 0
ode3 = h[x] == f[x] + g[x]
ics = {h[0] == 1, f'[0] == 0, g'[0] == 1};
system = {ode1, ode2, ode3}
soln = NDSolve[Join[system, ics], {f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 5}]
```

> { {f[x] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 5.}}, <>][x], 
>    g[x] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 5.}}, <>][x]} }

```
Plot[{f[x], g[x]} /. soln, {x, 0, 5}]
```

> [image: Plot of f[x] and g[x]]

Comment: Interesting, seems that `NDSolve` has introduced an artificial boundary `f[0] == 0.5` silently in this case, but there should be infinite solutions actually, see my answer.